# Defining an indexer for an object

Tags: javascript

One can make an object `iterable` by implementing `[Symbol.iterator]`.

But how can one override the behavior of the `[]` operator?

For example i have a an object which has an array inside of it and i want to be able to access that given an index like `obj[3]`.

is that possible?

example

```
const SignalArray = (data = []) => {
...
return {
        add,
        remove,
        onAdd,
        onRemove,
        onSort,
        removeOnAdd,
        removeOnRemove,
        removeOnSort,
        [Symbol.iterator]() {
            return {
                next: () => {
                    if (index < data.length) {
                        return { value: data[index++], done: false };
                    } else {
                        index = 0; 
                        return { done: true };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re treating `obj` as if it’s an array. Why not actually use the array itself? Don’t try and change the behaviour of inbuilt object.

Comment: Do you mean something like `var a = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b' }` ?

Comment: @Teemu if you hate es6 classes and want to write a wrapper around an array that gives it extra functionality, like an observable array for example, you could write a function called .at(index) but i would like do [index] if possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how can one override the behavior of the `[]` operator?

Only via [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), added in ES2015. You'd provide a [`get` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) and handle the property keys you want to handle.

Here's an example where we check for property names that can be successfully coerced to numbers and return the number `* 2`:

```js
const o = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    const v = +prop;
    if (!isNaN(v)) {
      return v * 2;
    }
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  }
});
o.x = "ex";
console.log(o[2]); // 4
console.log(o[7]); // 14
console.log(o.x);  // "ex"
```

If you want to override **setting** the array element, you'd use [`set` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set). There are several other traps available as well. For instance, in a reply to a comment, [you said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095027/defining-an-indexer-for-an-object#comment85195183_49095027):

> ...if you hate es6 classes and want to write a wrapper around an array that gives it extra functionality, like an observable array for example...

...that would probably involve a `set` trap and overriding various mutator methods.